# Couple applying for Express Entry in Canada: Who should be the primary applicant?

Tags: visa, working-visas, canada, resident-permit

I am a BE with 8 yrs of IT experience and my wife is a MS from USA with 6 years of Indian IT experience and we are planning to apply for Express Entry, considering myself to be the primary applicant but as my wife's points are more I am confused on who should be the primary applicant.

Also if a primary applicant applies for express entry along with spouse, will both of them get the PR? We both don't want to quit our jobs here and to minimize risk, it's better I go first, get a job and then take my wife.

Comment: I can't find a webpage to back this up, but yes, all people on an approved application will get permanent residency which will include the right to work.

Comment: Well.  If your plan is for you to go first, get a job and then take your wife then primary applicant would you.

Answer (score 2):

If your wife has more CSR points, she should be the primary applicant. However, the secondary applicant needs to arrive in Canada first. You can get around this by flying with your wife to Canada, going through the landing process, and having her return to your current country until you find a job.

Both applicants get PR through express entry.

[I immigrated through express entry this year and wrote about it in depth](http://15miles.info/cic-express-entry/). It might answer some of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter. Actually they will ask you to sign two forms: one with you and one with her as primary applicant and they will decide which one will be according to the number of points (they will pick what is more convenient for you).

You both get permanent residence it doesn't matter who is the primary applicant.
You both have to come at the same time, you will receive an one-entry visa that is only valid if you come as a couple. There's only one exception: if one of you dies. You cannot come separated, I know someone who got divorced and his wife didn't want to come, he was not allowed to enter.

If you want to come both and one of you wants to return then you will have to wait for 3 months for the permanent residence card to arrive, because you can leave but you cannot enter Canada again without it (visa is for one-entry only)